# Why is DataOutputStream in java not working as expected?

Tags: java, file-io, dataoutputstream

I am learning about file IO in java, and wanted to test this, but I am not sure why I am getting weird results. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

public class driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Hello.txt");
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
        dos.writeBoolean(true);
        dos.writeInt(68);
        dos.writeChar('c');
        dos.writeDouble(3.14);
        dos.writeFloat(56.789f);
    }
}
```

My input file `"Hello.txt` doesn't exist yet and I want to put all these values like 68, c, 3,14 etc into this file, however after running the above program, these are the contents of `"Hello.txt"`.

`D c@    ¸Që…Bc'ð`

So what exactly is happening here?

Comment: You're getting raw binary data written to the file; what did you expect?

Comment: I expected real data to be printed. So I guess this is the difference between DataOutputStream and FileOutputStream. Former gets raw data whereas the latter gets whatever is asked for?

Comment: No. You seem to be thinking of a `PrintStream`; assuming you want human readable text.

Comment: Which text editor, have you used to view the content of hello.txt ? I guess, you try to open it into notepad++ and set the encoding to "Encode In Ansi" and then see what type of text are you able to see ?

Comment: The output of `DataOutputStream` is binary, not text, and should not be saved in a file named `.txt`. Your expectations are incorrect.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, now I know what to expect from `DataOutputStream`. However, I have one more question, since you have said that it should be saved in a file named `.txt`, is there a better/conventional way to store `DataOutputStream` ?

Comment: I said it should *not* be saved in a file named `.txt`. Other possibilities include .dat, .bin, ...

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, but I was just asking as to which extension is usually used in such cases like is it .bin or .dat or something else? Which is "often" used?